# He happened + infin

Tags: infinitives, syntactic-analysis, transitive-verbs

> I happened **to see**...

In sentences like this, is the infinitive the object of happen? Can happen be transitive?

Comment: It seems to me that *happen* functions more like a modal in that construction. OED lists only one transitive sense and that a north-of-England regionalism, now rare.

Answer (score 1):

As BD points out, "happen" is intransitive in standard English.  You can tell because the transposition to the passive voice is impossible:

> To see was happened by me.

English has many verbs whose meaning is completed by an infinitive.  For a list of several dozen, go [here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html).

For some, the **infinitive** is an object:

> I promise **to write**.

The transposition to the passive, though unnatural, just barely works.  Others convey an adverbial sense of mode, manner, or explanation, and they can be said to modify the verb:

> A crowbar was used **to break** the lock.

But some, like "I happened to see" are simply idiomatic forms of more easily classifiable constructs (here, "I saw by chance").  We may call them verbs that take infinitive complements.

Comment: You mean **a *to*-infinitive:** lots of verbs are completed by infinitives without need of the *to* particle. “I made him work faster.” “I let her be by herself”.  “I helped him have a better day.”  The indirect object serves as subject of the infinitive clause.

Comment: @tchrist No, I mean an infinitive, particled or unparticled, without a direct object.  "It would help to know" and "He helped run the company."

Comment: In "He helped run the company", *the company* is the direct object.

Comment: @tchrist It's the object of the infinitive, not the direct object of "help."